# How to create a collections for particular type in js?

Tags: javascript

In C# i have a collection for a type like this.

```
 public class scale
 {

 }


 public class scales : List<scale>
 {
     // some codes.
 }
```

For scale, I used the functions like this:

```
scale = function ( )
{

}
```

How to create a scales (collections for a function) in js?

Comment: And for manipulating the list, you may use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) or [this](https://github.com/tadessetdk/jsList).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript currently has no proper concept of a collection type, just use the array type:

```
var scales = [];
scales.push(new scale());
```

You can still access the associated properties:

```
scales[0].myProp = "Hello";
```

You could define `scales` to be a class itself:

```
var scales = function() { this._items = []; };
scales.prototype = {
   add: function(scale) {
       this._items.push(scale);
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
var scales = new scales();
scales.add(new scale());
```

Comment: then how to create additional properties and functions in scales ?

Comment: If you are looking to do something a bit more complex, define `scales` to be a separate class.

Comment: is it posible to get value like this var s= scales[0].myProp instead of var s= scales._items[0].myProp while using the second approach ?

Comment: Not likely without extending the `Array.prototype` object instead of creating a new custom object - not generally a good idea to modify the built-in objects as you don't know what adverse affects it may have on other code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use arrays in JavaScript:

```
var scales = [];
scales.push(new scale());
// and so on...
```

But JavaScript is a dynamically typed language. You cannot enforce compile-time type safety and create an array that can only have `scale` instances.

#### EDIT 1

The `Array` class already has a few helper methods. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) for more information.

#### EDIT 2

By the way, it is true that the `scale` variable you have defined above is a function, but when you create a new instance of `scale` using the new operator, what you get is not a function any longer, but an object. So you don't create a "collections for a function", but a *collection for objects*.

Comment: then how to create additional properties and functions in scales ?